# Должен ли Front-end разработчик разбираться в компьютерных сетях?

Tags: frontend

Должен ли Front-end разработчик разбираться в компьютерных сетях, типа в том, как работает маршрутизатор, как он получает/отправляет запросы и т.д.? Или эти знания ему не нужны?

Comment: только базовые знания. как происходит запрос в бэку.

Comment: То есть, как я понял углубленные знания в этом не требуется?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для front разработчика важно понимать как происходит передача данных. Я бы хотел, чтоб он знал как происходит каждый пункт из тайминга запроса https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network/reference#timing-explanation

Answer (score 0):

Не должен, ибо эти знания не требуются для выполнения основной работы.

Разработчики в данном направлении имеют дело, в основном, с HTTP-протоколом, который является уровнем приложений, а не сетевым или передающим (транспортным), понимание которых есть составляющая понимания вычислительных (компьютерных) сетей.

Comment: Важно только понимать, как браузер принимает/отправляет запрос HTTP/HTTPS ?

Comment: @Ibrahim да. HTTP с которым работают разработчики это уровень приложений, а не сетевой и не передающий.